# Cannot read property of null React

Tags: reactjs, component

estoy aprendiendo react y al hacer algo de código:

```
import React from 'react'

 const span = document.getElementById('logo');
 let name = document.getElementById('name');


const showLogo =() => {
    if(name.innerHTML !== "algo"){
        name.innerHTML = 'algo'
    }else{
        name.innerHTML = 'otra cosa'
    }
}

const Header = () =>{

return (
    <nav>
        <div className="logo">
            <p><span id="logo" onClick={() => showLogo()}>&lt;dev&gt;</span><span id="name">dR</span><span>&lt;/dev&gt;</span></p>
        </div>
        <div className ="nav-items">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Portfolio</li>
                <li>Contacto</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
)



}
 export default Header
```

y me salta este error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es, donde tengo que colocar mi función para que cuando se renderice el componente, la función ya este "cargada"? o hay algún otro error que notan?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dices, el error es debido a que el `html`no esta cargado/generado al intentar buscar el elemento y por eso obtienes ese error. La solución a tu problema seria mover este código

```
 const span = document.getElementById('logo');
 let name = document.getElementById('name');
```

dentro de la función `showLogo` y funcionaria perfectamente ya que forzaría al programa a volver a buscar esos elementos cada vez que se haga click en este caso.

```
const showLogo = () => {
  const span = document.getElementById("logo");
  let name = document.getElementById("name");

  if (name.innerHTML !== "algo") {
    name.innerHTML = "algo";
  } else {
    name.innerHTML = "otra cosa";
  }
};
```

Aun que ya tienes la solución, me gustaría mostrar otras maneras de hacerlo o al menos las que yo usaría.

**Solución 1: Hacer uso del [estado](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do) del componente**

Esta solución te permite definir un estado por defecto y después de una acción cambiar el valor a mostrar en tu caso lo que provocara un nuevo renderizado con el valor actualizado, por ejemplo

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  // El valor por defecto sera 'algo'
  // useState como indica, te permite tener un estado en tus componentes de tipo "funciones"
  let [logoInfo, setLogoInfo] = useState("algo");
  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="logo">
        <p>
          <span
            id="logo"
            onClick={() => {
              // Cambiamos la información dependiendo del estado anterior
              logoInfo !== "algo"
                ? setLogoInfo("algo")
                : setLogoInfo("otra cosa");
            }}
          >
            &lt;dev&gt;
          </span>
          {/**Simplemente se muestra el valor  */}
          <span id="name">{logoInfo}</span>
          <span>&lt;/dev&gt;</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Portfolio</li>
          <li>Contacto</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

**Solución 2: Acceder al elemento usando [useRef](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)**

Si por cualquier necesidad necesitas tener acceso al elemento, ya sea para leer un atributo o hacer otra tipo de acción, puedes usar `useRef`

> No te recomiendo actualizar el valor de un elemento usando este método, ya que podría generar información incorrecta.

Ejemplo:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default () => {
  // Aqui guardaremos la referencia hacia el elemento
  let elemetRef = useRef(null);

  //Funcion a llamar cuando se haga click
  const showElement = () => {
    console.log(
      "El elemento es: ",
      elemetRef.current,
      " con el valor ",
      elemetRef.current.innerHTML
    );

    //Simplemente cambiamos el valor del elemento dependiendo de la condicion
    elemetRef.current.innerHTML !== "algo"
      ? (elemetRef.current.innerHTML = "algo")
      : (elemetRef.current.innerHTML = "otra cosa");

    // Y si estas "obligado" a usar getElementById, getElementsByClassName etc...
    // aquí lo puedes usar, ya que tienes el html generado y disponible para manipular
    console.log("Usando getElementById: ", document.getElementById("logo"));
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="logo">
        <p>
          <span id="logo" onClick={showElement}>
            &lt;dev&gt;
          </span>
          <span ref={elemetRef} id="name">
            {/**Simplemente se muestra el valor por defecto  */}
            algo
          </span>
          <span>&lt;/dev&gt;</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Portfolio</li>
          <li>Contacto</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a la documentación de react, esta disponible en español también y es bastante clara.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, muy clara! Gracias por tu tiempo!